# Rails: Issue with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I've built a simple_form form in my rails app and things went just fine:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@folha, @servico], html: {class: 'well form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.association :pessoa, label: 'Funcionário' %>
<%= f.input :funcao, label: 'Função',collection: @funcoes %>
<%= f.input :modulos, label: 'Módulos', input_html: {class: 'span4'} %>
<%= f.input :valor, label: 'Valor por hora', as: :string ,input_html: {class: 'span1'} %>
<%= f.input :horas, as: :string, input_html: {class: 'span1'} %>
<%= f.button :submit, 'Incluir', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

To change the order list on the dropdown for the f.association i've overwritten the default .all method in Pessoa.rb:

```
def self.all
  order :nome
end
```

Then i got this error when trying to render my view:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Extracted source (around line #5):

2:  <h1>Preencher Pagamentos - Folha <%= "#{@folha.mes}/#{@folha.ano}" %> <small> <%= @folha.obs %> </small> </h1>
3: </div>
4: <%= simple_form_for([@folha, @servico], html: {class: 'well form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
5: <%= f.association :pessoa, label: 'Funcionário' %>
6: <%= f.input :funcao, label: 'Função',collection: @funcoes %>
7: <%= f.input :modulos, label: 'Módulos', input_html: {class: 'span4'} %>
```

I think its better find a way to order the list in the view. But im very curious about what
is going on...

Comment: If you want to overwrite the `all` method, you should do `super.order :nome`. But it will be better to use `default_scope -> { order :nome }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not override those kind of methods in first place.

Here is how to do it with simple_form

```
f.association : pessoa, :collection => Pessoa.order(:nome).all
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/#associations

Answer (score 0):

You can use default_scope as described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class).

> Use this macro in your model to set a default scope for all operations on the model.

In your case `default_scope order(:nome)`.

Comment: I just saw it: Mirko Akkov already described this in the comments.